# I made a $60 transaction to my BTC wallet and I’ve only received half of it ands it’s been 4days

Tags: transactions, wallet, wallet-recovery

Can someone pls help or explain to me what’s going on.

Comment: You don't send dollars to BTC wallets, you send bitcoins. Did you send a different amount than what you received?

Comment: I put $60 in the Bitcoin atm so I can covert the $60 into bitcoin but only half of my money is in my wallet

Answer (score 1):

> **I put $60 in the Bitcoin atm so I can covert the $60 into bitcoin but only half of my money is in my wallet**

Bitcoin ATMs charge fees for currency exchange. Sometimes they use jaw-dropping spreads on exchange rates. They are usually very expensive. Possibly more so for small amounts. Check your receipt.

If you think the machine made a mistake, contact the operator (don't contact the owner of the floorspace, they mostly just rent the floorspace they don't own the machine).

> **and it’s been 4 days**

Waiting longer won't make any more BTC turn up. The transaction is done.

---

Footnote/Digression:

Bitcoin ATMs are not Automated Teller Machines (ATMs) they are automated currency exchanges, a different thing. Calling them BTMs is marginally better.

Comment: I’ll just never put $60 in at one time I’ll just put $20 in at a time

Comment: Should I have sent the bitcoin to my private key instead of public key

Comment: @ZoeGodGT it will be helpful to stop thinking in terms of "I sent this many dollars", and start thinking in terms of "I sent this amount of BTC". The issue of considering the $ value is compounded by the volatile nature of BTC. The price dropped in the last few days, so there is a good chance your bitcoin was probably just worth more at the time of purchase then it is now. Bitcoin is sent to bitcoin addresses, not private keys. Do not ever share a private key.